# Index of a maximal subgroup in a solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, solvable-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $p$ be a prime and $n$ be a positive integer. Is it possible to find a finite solvable group $G$ with a maximal subgroup $M$ such that $|G:M|=p^n$?

If $n=1$, we can surely find it taking a group of order $pq$ with a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. What if $n\geq 2$?

I can't even find examples of solvable groups with a maximal subgroup of cube prime index. Are there?

Comment: At this moment I can only think of $A_4$, having Sylow $3$-subgroups of index $4$. Maybe think of $(\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2)\rtimes\Bbb Z_3$?

Comment: Yes, $A_4$ is one particular example. But I was wondering if there is some generic construction which shows what I wanted or maybe some theorem saying that is not possible.

Comment: Edited previous comment. Not sure if the semi-direct product has a maximal Sylow $3$-subgroup or not...

Comment: I do not think so. The example has a non-trivial center, therefore one can always add it to the maximal subgroup.

Comment: Maybe $(\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2)\rtimes\Bbb Z_7$? Just a plain guess. Not sure if it has trivial center or not :P

Comment: I highly suspect that the above group of order $56$ has trivial center. Consider $w$ the generator of its Sylow $7$-subgroup. Then $w$ can be realised as the $7$-cycle in $GL(3,\Bbb F_2)$: $(x\space y\space xz\space z\space yz\space xy\space xyz)$, where $x,y,z$ are the generators of its Sylow $2$-subgroup. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p^n$ be a prime power and consider $G = \operatorname{AGL}(1, p^n)$, which is a semidirect product $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \rtimes \mathbb{F}_{p^n}^*$. Then $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^*$ is a maximal subgroup of index $p^n$ in $G$.